# MemoryError when fetching email with exchangelib

Tags: python-3.x, exchangelib

I have a question regarding saving email data in batches using exchangelib. Currently it is taking a lot of time if there are many emails. After a few minutes it throws this error:

```
    ERROR:    MemoryError:
    Retry: 0
    Waited: 10
    Timeout: 120
    Session: 25999
    Thread: 28148
    Auth type: <requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth object at 0x1FBFF1F0>
    URL: https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
    HTTP adapter: <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter object at 0x1792CE68>
    Allow redirects: False
    Streaming: False
    Response time: 411.93799999996554
    Status code: 503
    Request headers: {'X-AnchorMailbox': 'myworkemail@workdomain.com'}
    Response headers: {}
```

Here is the code that I use for connecting and reading:

```py
def connect_mail():
    config = Configuration(
        server="outlook.office365.com",
        credentials=Credentials(
            username="myworkemail@workdomain.com", password="*******"
        ),
    )
    return Account(
        primary_smtp_address="myworkemail@workdomain.com",
        config=config,
        access_type=DELEGATE,
    )

def import_email(account):
    tz = EWSTimeZone.localzone()
    start = EWSDateTime(2020, 10, 26, 22, 15, tzinfo=tz)
    for item in account.inbox.filter(
        datetime_received__gt=start, is_read=False
    ).order_by("-datetime_received"):
        email_body = item.body
        email_subject = item.subject
        soup = bs(email_body, "html.parser")
        tables = soup.find_all("table")
        item.is_read = True
        item.save()
        # Some code here for saving the email to a database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `MemoryError` which means that Python is not able to allocate any more memory on your machine.

There's a couple of things you can do to reduce memory consumption of your script. One is to use [.iterator()](https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/exchangelib/queryset.html#exchangelib.queryset.QuerySet.iterator) which disables internal caching of your query results. Another is to fetch only the fields you actually need using [.only()](https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/exchangelib/queryset.html#exchangelib.queryset.QuerySet.only)

When you're using `.only()`, the other fields will be `None`. You need to remember to only save the one field you actually changed: `item.save(update_fields=['is_read'])`

Here's an example of how to use the two improvements:

```py
for item in account.inbox.filter(
        datetime_received__gt=start, is_read=False,
    ).only(
        'is_read', 'subject', 'body',
    ).order_by('-datetime_received').iterator():
```

Comment: Thanks @erik-cederstrand , above code is working fine. However I still want to hear your thoughts on batch processing of emails. I want to save email data into mongo db through a cron job. above code might not work when the code pushed to server. that's the reason I want to read them in batches.

Comment: I would suggest that you find or open a new question for that, since saving data to mongodb in batch doesn't have anything to do with exchangelib.